# WinRT Xaml: Tapping Individual elements in grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I want to be able to individually figure out which children grids are tapped as part of a larger grid. Each of the children grid are in individual columns and rows, I'm trying to do something simple where I handle individual grids being tapped through different event handlers. What am I doing wrong? I can only get the entire grid to fire an event handler when it is tapped, but what I want is the event handler "row0col0_Tapped" to be fired only when that part of the 0th row and 0th column of the outer grid is tapped.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsTapEnabled="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="row0col0_Tapped">
        <Canvas x:Name="row0col0"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></Grid>

    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Grid>

    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
    <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the problem here ? don't you getting 'row0col0_Tapped' event?

Comment: No, the event is not being fired

Comment: set Main Grid Background as 'Transparent' & then check it

Comment: Try setting the IsTapEnabled of the main parent grid to false, then see if any of the child grids can fire then events?

Comment: @J.B i DON'T THINK SO BECAUSE ALL OTHER GRIDS ARE PLACED INSIDE THE MAIN GRID. SO CHILD ELEMENTS ALSO COULD NOT GET TAP EVENT WHEN YOU SET MAIN GRID 'IsTapEnabled ="fALSE'

Comment: You had to set the "BackGround" of the children grid to "Transparent", it doesn't work if you set the background of the main grid to transparent. Also if the "IsTapEnabled" is set to "False" for the main grid, the answer is still applicable, but this did not solve my problem initially.

Comment: i don't know how it did not work with my solution .anyway you got the answer .cool..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set a transparent back ground for the the grid which is to be tapped.

```
 <Grid IsTapEnabled="True" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"   Tapped="row0col0_Tapped">
    <Canvas x:Name="row0col0"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```